# how to print a triangle style result pattern

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I'm having difficulty making a triangle style result using either for or while loops. It should print:

> - 2
> - 2 4
> - 2 4 6
> - 2 4 6 8
> - 2 4 6 8 10....

This is what I have so far, any advice? It's much appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    for (int row = 2; row < 10; row+=2) {
        for (int col = 1; col < row ; col++ )
            System.out.print(col * row + "\t");
        System.out.println();                       
    }
}
```

Comment: `col` ranges from 1 to `row` (so, 1, 2, 3, ..., row-1). `row` ranges from 2 to 10 (so, 2, 4, 6, 8). You are printing out `col * row`. Let's say `row` is 6. This will yield `1 * 6`, `2 * 6`, `3 * 6`, etc, yet you say you want your subsequence to always start from `2`. Do you see what's wrong?

Comment: i'm using a multiplication table xD i see it

Answer (score 0):

```
    String SPACE =" ";
    int numberOfCols = 1;

    while (numberOfCols < 5) {

        int colCounter = 1;
        for( int i = 2; i<= 10; i+=2) {
            System.out.print(i + SPACE);
            if(colCounter ++ > numberOfCols)    break;
        }
        System.out.println();
        numberOfCols++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To print right aligned triangle, you need to increment the width for every iteration and print only the even numbers in your case.

multiplying row and columns is not required, you can simply print even number in the col

Try this

```
private static void printPattern(int rows) {
    for (int row = 2; row <= 2 * rows; row += 2) {
        for (int col = 2; col <= row; col += 2) {
            System.out.print(col + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

output : rows = 10

```
2 
2 4 
2 4 6 
2 4 6 8 
2 4 6 8 10 
2 4 6 8 10 12 
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

Comment: please explain what is wrong with his solution and how you have corrected it

Comment: @Blip sure will add

Answer (score 0):

I do think you did not dry-run your program. Other wise you would have understood your problem.

For the first Outer loop `row` stores 2. In the inner loop `col` can attain value of 1 as the exit condition of the loop is `col` < `row`. so when the `col` attains the value of 2 it exits the loop so only `2` is printed.

Now for the second iteration of the outer loop `row` stores 4. In the inner loop `col` starts with value of 1 stored. So the first print will be `4 X 1` i.e. 4. then the `col` attains the value of 2 So the print will be `4X2` i.e. 8. and so on . This is not what you want. So re-think your issues.